# Error (Xcode, Swift): JSON could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I made an app a couple years ago and am trying to update it now. When I run my Alamofire request, I am getting an message that, "JSON could not be serialized because of error: The data couldn't be read because it isn't in the correct format." To clarify, this is not crashing my app. Rather it is not pulling any data when it should, and returning the above message.

I've updated my cocoapods, but I haven't coded in a while so I am not really sure what the issue is.

```
let brandName = restaurantField.text!
        let foodName = itemNameField.text!
//        let url = "https://api.nutritionix.com/v2/search/"
        let url = "https://trackapi.nutritionix.com/v2/search/"

        let params = [
            "appId":"66ebb194",
            "appKey":"2e43991be685bcd5836574dda12e4625",
            "queries":[
                "food_name":foodName,
                "brand_name":brandName
            ],
            "fields":["item_name","brand_name","nf_total_carbohydrate","nf_serving_size_qty","nf_serving_size_unit"],
            "filters":[
                "item_type":1
            ]
            ] as [String : Any]
        
        AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { response in
            switch (response.result) {
            case .success:
                print("Request: \(String(describing: response.request))")   // original url request
                print("Response: \(String(describing: response.response))") // http url response
                print("Result: \(response.result)")                         // response serialization result
                
                //old syntax - swift 3
//                if let json = response.result.value {
//                    print("JSON: \(json)") //  serialized json response
//
//                }
                switch response.result {
                case let .success(value):
                    print(value)
                case let .failure(error):
                    print(error)
                    
                    print("\n\n===========Error===========")
                            print("Error Code: \(error._code)")
                            print("Error Messsage: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            if let data = response.data, let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8){
                                print("Server Error: " + str)
                            }
                            debugPrint(error as Any)
                            print("===========================\n\n")
                }
                
                if let data = response.data, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                    print("Data: \(utf8Text)") // original server data as UTF8 string
                    let json = try! JSON(data: response.data!)
                    if let objects = json["hits"].array{
                        for object in objects{
                            self.items.append(Item(json: object.dictionaryValue))
                            print(self.items)
                            print(self.items[0].carbs)
                            self.tableView.reloadData()
                            self.itemNameField.text = ""
                            self.restaurantField.endEditing(true)
                            self.itemNameField.endEditing(true)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if self.items.count == 0{
                        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No results from search", message: nil, preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
                        let ok = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
                        })
                        alert.addAction(ok)
                        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
                    break
            case .failure(let error):
                
                print("\n\n===========Error===========")
                        print("Error Code: \(error._code)")
                        print("Error Messsage: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        if let data = response.data, let str = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8){
                            print("Server Error: " + str)
                        }
                        debugPrint(error as Any)
                        print("===========================\n\n")
                if error._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                    
                }
```

Hopefully this is enough information for a solution, but please let me know if there's other things I should provide.

Below is a printout of the error description...

```
Error Messsage: JSON could not be serialized because of error:
The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format.
Server Error: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot POST /v2/search/</pre>
</body>
</html>

Alamofire.AFError.responseSerializationFailed(reason: Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around line 1, column 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around line 1, column 0., NSJSONSerializationErrorIndex=0}))
```

Comment: Check the incoming JSON. It likely isn't valid, as the error indicates. Alternately, if the error is coming from the server, validate that the JSON you're sending is correct. It looks like you've changed servers. They may have changed their API.

Comment: Use `print(error)` instead your get a better error it will tell you exactly what is wrong

Comment: I edited the question to include the print(error) output

Comment: you are getting an HTML/XML error, it's quite explicit, it says you can't do a `POST` only a `GET` there. `method: .post` -> `method: .get`?

Comment: Unrelated, but `responseJSON()` is deprecated. In fact, this does an inner call to `JSONSerialization` that also do your code `JSON(data:)`. In recent Swift, prefer using `Codable`.

Comment: @Larme thank you for your response. I tried doing .get and get an error including 
`URLRequest validation failed due to reason: Invalid URLRequest: Requests with GET method cannot have body data:`           followed by my query for the API. I am struggling to understand what changed from when this worked to now. Do you know if this is a problem with my API or with my Alamofire?

Comment: You should learn the difference between a HTTP GET and POST but more importantly, since you get an error message that you can’t use post then clearly the api you are using has changed so you need to check the documentation for it to learn how you need to adjust your http call.